# A PowerShell command executed through runas.exe

Tags: powershell, escaping, double-quotes

I need to execute the PS command through *runas.exe*. The PS command works separately, but I can't make it work as a runas.exe call. Seems to be an escaping issue, but quotes + double-quotes don't work here for some reason :(

The original command:

```bash
runas.exe /savecred /user:user "cmd.exe /k powershell -Command "& {echo 123}""
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
:: From cmd.exe
runas.exe /savecred /user:user "powershell -NoExit -Command \"^& { echo 123 }\""
```

- There is no need to call via `cmd /k` - passing `-NoExit` to `powershell.exe` directly keeps the session open.
- The *embedded* `"` inside your overall `"..."` string must be *escaped*, as `\"`

  - Unfortunately, because `cmd.exe` itself - unlike `runas.exe` - doesn't recognize `\"` as an escaped `"` and therefore considers it a *closing* `"` for the outer starting `"`, as a result of which it considers the `&` to be *outside* `"..."`, which would cause interpretation as `cmd.exe`'s statement-sequencing operator. Escaping `&` as `^&` avoids that.
    Note that other `cmd.exe` metacharacters, such as `|`, would have to be `^`-escaped too.

---

You can ***avoid or lessen* the need for `^`-escaping** by taking advantage of the fact that [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, also allows you to pass the components of a command string as *individual arguments*, i.e. without overall `"..."` enclosure:

```bash
:: From cmd.exe. 
:: No embedded "..." enclosure for the -Command arguments -> no need to ^-escape &
runas.exe /savecred /user:user "powershell -NoExit -Command & { echo 123 }"
```

Further, note that **you don't need `& { ... }` around a command you pass to `-Command`** - just use the command *directly*:

```bash
:: From cmd.exe. 
:: No need for & { ... }
runas.exe /savecred /user:user "powershell -NoExit -Command echo 123"
```

All that said, **you can still run afoul of `cmd.exe`'s parsing**, namely when the PowerShell command *itself* requires `"` characters (as opposed to using `"` merely *syntactically* for the initial *command line*):

The following makes PowerShell print *verbatim* `3" of snow & more`:

```bash
runas.exe /savecred /user:tu1 "powershell -NoExit -Command echo '3\\\" of snow ^& more'"
```

Note the need to *doubly* escape the `"` character (`\\\"`, to first escape for `runas.exe`, and then for `powershell.exe`), and again the need to `^`-escape `&` for the benefit of `cmd.exe`.

Comment: You're breathtaking!